# Convert persistent collection to hash map

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to convert persistent collection "one to many" attribute to hash map , for example i have department object which have many employees , when i want to retrieve employees like this

> department->getEmployees()

I want to get hash map like this

> [employeeId]=>[employeeName]

So i can retrieve employee by their id faster.

Comment: This http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html might help you

Comment: Thank you , i will check this site.

Comment: @VadimAshikhman that should be an answer, not a comment.